# How can I find the parameters needed to steer an ultrasonic beam?

Tags: signal-processing, phase, transducer

To be honest, I don't know if this question is more appropriate for Stack Overflow, Software Engineering, or Physics, so apologies in advance if I guessed wrong.

I'm trying to build a 3D ultrasound machine out of commercially available parts (just to see if I can). In order to do that, I need to be able to scan an ultrasonic beam from a fixed array of transducers.

I've tried Googling beam steering techniques, and everything I find is big on theory and noticeably short on practicals.

So, is there an algorithm that will tell me the phase angle, intensity, etc. I need to use for each transducer to point the beam in a certain direction? If that's not possible (I rather strongly suspect that that one's NP-Complete), is there an algorithm that will predict the beam angle that I can use as a fitness function?

Comment: Where's the simulation in this?  Please try to pick more suitable tags.  If you can't find one, that may indicate something about your question.

Comment: @pjs I was thinking along the lines that I'd be simulating the performance of the array. I've changed the tags, better?

Comment: Since you will be building this fixed array, I assume you have some freedom with the geometry of the array, but you likely also have some constraints (e.g. number of transducers, machine size, etc.) If your constraints allow, you may want to start experimenting with a linear [phased array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phased_array), and a simple delay-and-sum beamformer. There will often be a lot of theory & maths in those algorithms, but if you settle on some specifics geometry and have some simulation setup & goal, we may be able to steer you in the right direction (no pun intended).